# Designing a database for private clinic

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-design, oracle18c

I am using db 18C XE AND APEX 21.1. I am designing a database for private clinics. A private clinic is a place where patients get diagnosed. The clinic has only one doctor and an assistant or two. The assistant records the patients' data and visits(admission) data. The patient gets diagnosed at the first visit and get a prescription with the drugs they should take. Then a follow-up or more visits follows afterward i.e the second visit is after two weeks then a third one after a month and so on. Each follow-up has a new prescription or maybe the same prescription if the doctor thinks there is no need for a new drug. The patient could be diagnosed for a disease then gets cured after a number of visits. Then he could visit the clinic again after a year or two for a different complain. The same process occurs again. I am attaching a photo of the part of the visits, examining and follow-ups. I want to be sure if I designed it correctly.
[image]

Comment: Not the kind of question stackOverfow is designed to answer, I'm afraid. I'm sure you have justification for all your design decisions; run with it and change anything you need to as time goes on

Comment: How is it not?! It's about database design and there is a tag named database design!

Comment: "Hi guys, what is your opinion on my design" is not on topic, sorry. It matters not what the tags are, it's based purely on how the question is asked. Present us with an actual problem you're facing in doing your data modelling (like "with these existing tables, how to track which user took which drug on which day?"), rather than "did I do it right?"

Comment: It's not an opinion based question. It's a right or wrong question based on the principles of database design.

Comment: Sure it is; design is an opinion. I wouldn't have designed the database the way you have. Asking "is my design right" requires an answer that starts "in my opinion..". Compare a question like "how do I write a for loop in c# that simultaneously iterates two collections of the same size, one forwards, one backwards" - there's only really one answer to that one

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am able understand your use case, the follow up table will record the follow up visits of the patient. Since you have columns like dose, drug_id etc in FOLLOW_UP_PRESCRIPTION table, I think there must be a patient id as well to map drugs/medicines with the patient.

Correct me if I'm missing something